# Generating scoreboards on large traffic sites

Tags: php, usability

Bit of an odd question but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Basically I have two scenarios and I'd like to know which one is the best for my situation (a user checking a scoreboard on a high traffic site).

1. Top 10 is regenerated every time a user hits the page - increase in load on the server, especially in high traffic, user will see his/her correct standing asap.
2. Top 10 is regenerated at a set interval e.g. every 10 minutes. - only generates one set of results causing one spike every 10 minutes rather than potentially once every x seconds, if a user hits in between the refresh they won't see their updated score.

Each one has it's pros and cons, in your experience which one would be best to use or are there any magical alternatives?

**EDIT** - An update, after taking on board what everyone has said I've decided to rebuild this part of the application. Rather than dealing with the individual scores I'm dealing with the totals, this is then saved out to a separate table which sort of acts like a cached data source.

Thank you all for the great input.

Comment: How are the scoreboards being generated? I think the ideal solution is somewhere in between: Generate the scorecards only when there is new data to incorporate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Marcel's answer, I would suggest only updating the scoreboards upon write events (like new score or deleted score).  This way you can keep static answers for popular queries like Top 10, etc.  Use something like MemCache to keep data cached up for requests, or if you don't/can't install something like MemCache on your server serialize common requests and write them to flat files, and then delete/update them upon write events.  Have your code look for the cached result (or file) first, and then iff it's missing, do the query and create the data

Comment: This way, you can have 'real time' results and minimize the load of a recalculation or a DB query

Comment: I re-factored the system to do exactly this. Results are now cached for 15 minutes and database access only occurs when a new score is added to the system.

Again thanks for all the great suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is never needed real time when it comes to the web.  I would go with option 2 users will not notice that there score is not changing.  You can use some JS to refresh the top 10 every time the cache has cleared

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan)'s suggestion: I'd put the scorecards in a separate (HTML formatted) file, that is produced every time when new data arrives and only then. You can include this file in the PHP page containing the scorecard or even let a visitor's browser fetch it periodically using XMLHttpRequests (to save bandwidth). Users with JavaScript disabled or using a browser that doesn't support XMLHttpRequests (rare these days, but possible) will just see a static page.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal voting module will handle this for you, giving you an option of when to recalculate.  If you're implementing it yourself, then caching the top 10 somewhere is a good idea - you can either regenerate it at regular intervals or you can invalidate the cache at certain points.  You'd need to look at how often people are voting, how often that will cause the top 10 to change, how often the top 10 page is being viewed and the performance hit that regenerating it involves.

If you're not set on Drupal/MySQL then CouchDB would be useful here.  You can create a view which calculates the top 10 data and it'll be cached until something happens which causes a recalculation to be necessary.  You can also put in an http caching proxy inline to cache results for a set number of minutes.